# Border on <li></li> items including image styled bullets

Tags: html, css

How can i put a border on a `<li>` item including the styled bullets.

```
li{
   border:solid 1px gray;
}
```

CSS rule above will only give a border to the text contents of `<li></li>` and the border is not extended to the bullets which I have styled as png icons.

How can i get the bottom border on each li to extend to the list bullets as in the second screenshot?

**Current Output**

[image]

**Desired Output**
[image]

Comment: Without knowing how you have created the list / bullets it's hard to help. Please provide your HTML & CSS in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like so:

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Your bullet is by default outside the `<li>` element.

Comment: Nice, except this also left-justifies the bullet, which is normally right-justified.

Answer (score 1):

Add `list-style-position : inside` to the `ul`.
Here... https://jsfiddle.net/dzrcL79o/

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
ul {
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Verdana;
    list-style-position: inside;
}

li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```